# mongodb - Replica set creation error: Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I am configuring a mongodb replica set. From my current primary node, when `rs.add('host1:27017')`, it yields this error

```
Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively; failed with Server min and max wire version are incompatible (7,7) with client min wire version (6,6)
```

On my `host1` and `host2` machines, I already added `replication` option with the same `replSetName`, `bind_ip`, and exposed firewall. As a proof, through command line `mongo --host host1` I can still connect to `host1`'s mongo instance. The `telnet` command also yields the same successful connection. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I once experienced this error when primary node and other nodes are not the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that all 3 machines must have the same version 4.0